# Multiple Code Projects with single source code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

my current repository(net-core) has two projects in it, net-core.api, net-core.client, net-core.model

```
net-core 
    -> net-core.api
    -> net-core.client
```

Currently I am trying to make a pipeline to manage this repository when there's new code committed. I have 3 builds successfully created.

Build for net-core.api buildspec builds the project and we then have a manual button to deploy to containers or not.

The issue we currently have is if we choose not to deploy the net-core.api, we aren't able to get to the next stage.

Stage 1.

```
Source
```

Stage 2.

```
-> net-core.API            
    -> Approve Build       
        -> Deploy
```

Stage 3.

```
-> net-core.client
   -> Approve Build
       -> Publish Nuget
```

I could achieve this by have multiple pipelines but we are wondering if it's possible to achieve all this within one pipeline.

Something like this

```
Source
-> net-core.API            -> net-core.client
    -> Approve Build           -> Approve Build
        -> Deploy                 -> Publish Nuget
```